# Does SharePoint 2010 still have the complicated SPWeb.Dispose methods?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

One of my gripes with SharePoint 2007 are the complicated SPWeb.Dispose rules that can either cause a big resource leak if you don't dispose what you have to, or all sorts of other weird issues if you dispose when you don't have to. [Roger Lamb's Posting](http://blogs.msdn.com/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx) tries to summarize the madness. but I wonder if SharePoint 2010 improves this?

I have the Beta setup but don't really see much difference here, but was some of the stuff at least improved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You still need to carefully dispose of SPSite and SPWeb instances in SharePoint 2010. The last I checked, SPDisposeCheck had not been updated for SharePoint 2010. If it hasn't already been released, I'm certain it will be soon.

Comment: Thanks. Oh well, let's hope that they fix that in Sharepoint 2014 :)

Comment: By the time 2014 comes out, you will know what to dispose and what not to dispose :) But ofcourse, let's hope.

Comment: FYI, the SPDisposeCheck tool still works fine for the 2010 OM; nothing's really changed around the managed resources and when they need to be explicitly disposed.